# How to have multiple forms of same type inside a table in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

How to have multiple forms of same type inside a table in Django. I have a send email button on every row of a table with multiple columns. Once the user clicks on send email button there should be a form in which the user can enter email IDs and message and pull data form the specific row. I am new to django and not sure how to create multiple forms for these buttons. Can some one please help

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with nesting tables?

Comment: Every form will have the same name/ID when, I click on submit the javascript will take values from which form ID ??

Comment: Why do you need JavaScript for the buttons?

Comment: I am using twitter boothstrap to call a modal, inside the model I have a form which will take inputs from the user and then submit the form.
1.         <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-mini" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-envelope"></i>SendEmail</a>
Is there some other way of achieving this in Django ? I have never done this before and trying to lean. Can you please refer me to any resource which can help me in moving ahead.

Comment: Sounds more like you have a JavaScript problem than a Django problem; Django has no issue with generating multiple forms.